# JavaFX. AutoResize ComboBox при изменении Scene

Tags: java, javafx

**Вопрос:** как сделать расширяемый ComboBox? Чтобы при расширении окна мышкой, ComboBox тоже расширялся. Требуется чтобы обязательно слева от ComboBox был Label.

**Код:** (fxml)

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
  <AnchorPane>
     <children>
        <Label text="Label" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
  <AnchorPane>
     <children>
        <ComboBox AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
</children>
</HBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnchorPane для таких задач не подходит. Вам необходимо использовать другой контейнер, например, [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html).

Пример fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <left>
      <Label text="Label" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <center>
      <ComboBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: спасибо, нашел ответ через HBox, думаю BorderPane будет громоздко, хотя и интересно что у BorderPane это поведение есть по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
  <AnchorPane HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
     <children>
        <Label text="Label" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
  <AnchorPane HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES">
    <children>
        <ComboBox AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
</children>
</HBox>
```